# How can I send "List<Object>" object from View to Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to, pass the list of objects, from view to the controller's action. I gave "List<API_VM> model, IList<API_VM> model, API_VM[] model" as parameters on action and I gave "IList<API_VM>, List<API_VM>" as model on View page. but it doesn't work. Model is null all time.

```
 [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult UrunlerListe(API_VM model)
    {
        XElement stok = XElement.Load(model.TedarikciLink);
       List<API_VM> ApiList = new List<API_VM>();
        model.Stoklar = stok.Descendants(model.ParentElement).ToList();
        ViewBag.Tedarikci = model.TedarikciLink;
        foreach (var item in model.Stoklar)
        {
            API_VM api = new API_VM();
            api.UrunAdi = item.Element(model.UrunAdi).Value;
            api.Kategori = item.Element(model.Kategori).Value;
            api.UrunAciklama = item.Element(model.UrunAciklama).Value;
            api.UrunFiyat = item.Element(model.UrunFiyat).Value;
            api.UrunMarka = item.Element(model.UrunMarka).Value;
            api.PaketAgirligi = item.Element(model.PaketAgirligi).Value;
            api.PaketGenisligi = item.Element(model.PaketGenisligi).Value;
            api.PaketUzunlgu = item.Element(model.PaketUzunlgu).Value;
            api.PaketYuksekligi = item.Element(model.PaketYuksekligi).Value;
            api.StokAded = item.Element(model.StokAded).Value;
            api.UrunFoto1 = item.Element(model.UrunFoto1).Value;
            api.UrunFoto2 = item.Element(model.UrunFoto2).Value;
            api.UrunFoto3 = item.Element(model.UrunFoto3).Value;
            api.UrunFoto4 = item.Element(model.UrunFoto4).Value;
            api.UrunFoto5 = item.Element(model.UrunFoto5).Value;
            api.UrunFoto6 = item.Element(model.UrunFoto6).Value;
            
            ApiList.Add(api);
        }
        
        return View(ApiList);
    }
```

```html
@model IList<API_VM>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "UrunlerListe";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";


}
<form asp-action="UrunlerListe" method="post">

    @for (int i = 0; i <Model.Count(); i++)
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model[i].UrunAdi)
    }
    <input type="submit" value="ürünleri gönder" />
</form>
```

```
 [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult UrunlerListe(API_VM[] model)
    {
        //work
    }
```

Comment: whether it is mvc core or mvc

Comment: I test the demo and it works.Maybe you can share more about your view or controller.Or debug it to share more error message,such as the data you passed from view to controller.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [List of Model Object Post to Controller in ASP.NET MVC](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/855577/List-of-Model-Object-Post-to-Controller-in-ASP-NET) , this is similar to your requirement.

Moreover you can also refer [Pass (Send) List of objects from View to Controller using jQuery AJAX in ASP.Net MVC](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Pass-Send-List-of-objects-from-View-to-Controller-using-jQuery-AJAX-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx) this article.

Comment: <form asp-action="UrunlerListe" method="post" asp-controller="controlername">

Comment: Already they are in same controller. I tried all ways I know but still I can't do that. Model is null all time.